# select dropdown value based on session variable

Tags: php, forms, session, drop-down-menu

i have a php form which submits data to another php for validation. if any fields are left blank the validator php sends a message back to original php form along with all the pre filled variables using session variables so that user doesn't have to fill them again.

i can use these session variables to fill in text boxes again like this

```
value="<?php echo $_SESSION['fname'] ?>"
```

but how to go about populating drop downs, radio buttons and check boxes?

thanks

Comment: As with the INPUT element of type TEXT, you go with all other INPUT elements.

Comment: drop down box has selected option no input option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<select>` element's selected `<option>` is not determined by it's `value=` attribute. In order to mark an option selected, the `<option>` element must have the `selected` attribute set on it, as follows:

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option selected>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

In order to do this programmatically, you need to iterate through the options, and manually test for the correct option, and add `selected` to that.

Answer (score 4):

For a select, checkbox or radio box you would need to check whether the values match.  Something like:

```
<select name="fname">
 <option value="1" <?php if($_SESSION['fname'] == 1) echo 'selected'; ?>>1</option>
 <option value="2" <?php if($_SESSION['fname'] == 2) echo 'selected'; ?>>2</option>
</select>
```

It's easier if you are iterating through the values for the option field:

```
<select name="fname">
 <?php foreach($array AS $key => $value) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>" <?php if($_SESSION['fname'] == $value) echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo $value; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: cant get it to work ,  "2" is always selected when page reloads

Answer (score 1):

There is a far simpler method using JQuery. You can set Selects with .val() so make the most of it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#fname").val("<?php echo $_SESSION['fname']; ?>");
</script>
```

Don't forget to set the id of the select as well as the name to **fname**.

Answer (score 1):

... Noticed that your double quote at the end of the statement was misplaced, it should be:

```
<script>
    $("#fname").val("<?php echo $_SESSION['fname'] ?>");
</script>
```